# How to crawl pictures via python beautiful soup

Tags: python, image, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to crawl and download the image from a website, but I don't know why I receive an error when running this code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlretrieve


url = 'https://www.thsrc.com.tw/tw/TimeTable/SearchResult'
response = requests.get(url)
response.encoding = 'utf-8'

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
all_imgs = soup.find_all('img')

for index, img in enumerate(all_imgs):
    if index!=0:
        print(img['src'])
        image_path = 'https://www.thsrc.com.tw'+img['src']
        image_name = img['src'].split('/')[-1]
        print('image path is {}, file name is {}'.format(image_path, image_name))
        urlretrieve(image_path, 'save_image/'+image_name)
```

> And this is what I received:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

For some reasons there is a whitespace in the `img['src']`, so you have to `strip()` it:

```
image_path = 'https://www.thsrc.com.tw'+img['src'].strip()
```

###### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlretrieve

url = 'https://www.thsrc.com.tw/tw/TimeTable/SearchResult'
response = requests.get(url)
response.encoding = 'utf-8'

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)

for img in soup.find_all('img'):
    print(img['src'])
    image_path = 'https://www.thsrc.com.tw'+img['src'].strip()
    image_name = img['src'].split('/')[-1]
    print('image path is {}, file name is {}'.format(image_path, image_name))
    urlretrieve(image_path, 'save_image/'+image_name)
```